# How LastPass decrypts database on web browser?

Tags: encryption, aes, symmetric, authentication

According to video from Dr. Pound, password managers (LastPass in particular) holds encrypted image of your data on their servers and then with master password you authenticate to get encrypted image to client side where decryption is done.

- How is this handled when you login to lastpass website with browser?
- Is your browser decrypting data?
- If you change password - is your database reencrypted? If yes, how do they know the password (to get decryption key first) if you forgot it and change it through email change?

For mobile it is easier - data are synced down first - then local manager does the job.

https://youtu.be/w68BBPDAWr8

Comment: This question is off topic on Crypto SE.